# Is it possible to stick vertices, and for them not to be affect by proportional editing

Tags: vertices, vertex-colors

I have a tablet/pill shape, and I want to select all the outer vertices or edges, and have them stay where they are, so that when I do a proportional edit, they remain fixed, and so the edges/vertices are stretched rather than move around.

This is the effect I am trying to get - a bulge in the dark meshed areas
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP7NQ.jpg

If I use proportional editing, it alters the edges also.

So is there anyway of selecting the outer vertices, make them stick?

I have tried to create a vertex group, and assign a weight but it hasnt worked yet. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxFRy.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was enlightened.

- I select the object
- Edit mode
- Select the vertices that I want to stick
- Press 'H' to hide
- Make my adjustment
- Those vertices that are hidden will not be affected
- Press 'alt-H' to unhide.